# Is there any good way to hide and show the address/url bar for Chrome Mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, mobile

I am working on a webapp that uses several nested iframes.

This creates an issue where the url bar does not get hidden when scrolling down. I suspect this is because I am scrolling in one of the child iframes and not in the top level window.

Is there any good way to programatically hide and show the url bar?

I have tried the `scrollTo(0,1)` trick, but it only scrolls the page (quite annoyingly too) and doesn't affect the url bar.

I've also looked into fullscreen, but I don't want to use that for various reasons.

Comment: As far I am aware the only two viable options are full screen and the scroll trick. If you don't want to use either I am not sure you can hide and show the address url.

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate on why you don't want to use fullscreen? (not wanting to use the scroll trick is understandable)

Comment: @LiamHealy Fullscreen mode hurts performance and it locks the user in to fullscreen, preventing the use of the url bar at all. I could get around this by including a button that toggles the mode, but my UI is already full and out of my hands.

Comment: Would you maybe like me to help you move around some of the stuff in the UI? I don't know of any other way to hide the address bar that doesn't include the beforementioned methods...

Comment: I've been working on this problem for over a week now and I don't think there is any way to get around it based on my constraints. Thanks for trying though.